# How can I dynamically create dates between a specific timespan and weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following customer table:

```
ID | StartDate  | WeekCount
1  | 01.12.2015 | 2
2  | 03.12.2015 | 4
3  | 06.06.2014 | 8
```

The `Startdate` represents the date the customer gets the first visit, `WeekCount` is for the next visit (every X Weeks)

I want to query the next visit dates for a timespawn.

Lets say the first visit is **03.12.2015** then I query for **March 2016** so the expected date should be **03.03.2015**.

So basically `StartDate+WeekCount` and then the Date between filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `recursive CTE` will help you to solve your problem.

```
DECLARE @to_date DATETIME
SET @to_date = N'2016.03.01'

;WITH test_data AS(
    SELECT 1 AS id, CAST(N'2015.12.01' AS DATETIME) AS startDate, 2 AS weekCount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, CAST(N'2015.12.03' AS DATETIME) AS startDate, 4 AS weekCount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, CAST(N'2014.06.06' AS DATETIME) AS startDate, 8 AS weekCount
),
result_tbl AS(
    SELECT id, startDate, weekCount FROM test_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, DATEADD(ww, R.weekCount, R.startDate), weekCount FROM result_tbl AS R
    WHERE R.startDate < @to_date
)

SELECT * FROM result_tbl
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the datatype is date/datetime

```
Select columns from your_table
where StartDate>='20160301' and StartDate<'20160401'
```

Comment: Sry thats not correct. I want to generate StartDate+WeekCount and then get only results that match my timespan